# Reference to lower bound on separator in a grid?

Tags: reference-request, cg.comp-geom, lower-bounds

It is easy to verify that given the d dimensional grid of the integer points $\{1,\ldots,n\}^d$, with the regular adjacency, one can find a separator of size $n^{d-1}$ (just pick any middle hyperplane, and remove all its vertices). It is also not too hard (but definitely not immediate) to verify that any separator has to be of size $\Omega(n^{d-1})$. Anybody knows a refenence to this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like the book "[Graph separators, with applications](https://doi.org/10.1007/b115747)" by Arnold Rosenberg and Lenwood Heath answers your question (see section 4.3.4.), but it could happen that I misunderstood their notation (please, let me know). Anyway, this book is a very comprehensive reference on separators.

Comment: In fact, it is application 4.2.9 on page 177 of this book. I did not know that this book existed... Now I would have to get it. Thanks.

Comment: an excellent reference !